# Execute a bash file located on a different VPS

Tags: php, debian

I have a php webpage located on `Webserver1`, which is from `Host1`.

I also have a bash script located in `Gameserver1` which is from `Host2`.

Is there any way to send a command from `Webserver1` to `Gameserver1` to execute the bash file? The webpage and file are on different VPSs. Both are running Debian 7.

The script is literally one line, to execute a java command via a screen, so the server can start if a player notices it's down. The command's available already so it doesn't need to be a secure way of hiding what the command is.

Comment: @Jay I'm not asking for the best way, I'm asking for any way. How is this opinionated?

Comment: @Jay The thing about programming is that there's almost *always* more than one way to go about something - if there was only one way it's a basic language which *probably* isn't very good. I'm asking for any answer, not the best.

Comment: @Jay he is asking a question, if there is a method to do what he wants. he is not expecting opinions, he is expecting methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways I can think of. either create a bash file in `Webserver1` that connects through ssh and executes the bash script you need on `Gameserver1`. then run it through php with `exec()` command.

Or you can create a php file in `Gameserver1` that uses `exec()` to execute the bash script you need on `Gameserver1` and call it using `file_get_contents()` on `Webserver1`, which is not that secure since anyone can call that file and run your script.

Comment: What's the second idea? Thanks for this one by the way.

Comment: Oh and the script is literally one line, to execute a java command via a screen, so the server can start if a player notices it's down. The command's available already so it doesn't need to be secure.

Comment: then use the second method.